# Use Eloquent or Laravel to find items in two columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have no idea where / how to start on this.

I have a POST sending two values. `Public` and `Private`.  I need to make sure that the `public` and `private` items are in the same row in the database.

It's kind of like matching a username / password, but these are just values in two different columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
$model = Model::where(Input::only('public', 'private'))->first();
```